# How am I supposed to debug Image Capture intent, with USB debug

Tags: java, android

When taking a photo via `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent, how can I debug this code?

I cannot have debugger attached, as I cannot take a photo without SD card

When I disconnect the USB, I don't see debug in LogCat, and neither ACRA is not givin me result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to change your phones default behavior when connected over usb.  you likely have it set to auto mount as usb storage whenever connected to your computer. there should be an option (often accessible through the usb notification when your phone is plugged in) to set your phone to only charge when connected . try to find this and it will solve your problem.

Comment: dear god, I completely forgot, this is not the default behavior. I thought it's given to mount storage as I connect it in debug mode. Thanks